# R conditional data frame within Loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a loop, and I'm trying to do calculations based on various dataframes depending on where in the loop I'm at.

For example, lets say I have:
 `analyses <- c("red", "green", "blue")`

If I'm at the "red" stage, I want to use dataframe A within the loop. However if I'm at the "green" stage, I want to use dataframe B, and if I'm at the "blue" stage, I want to sue dataframe C.

```
for (i in analyses) {
  variable <- case_when(
    i == "red" ~ data.frame.a,
    i == "green" ~ data.frame.b,
    i == "blue" ~ data.frame.c
  )

[Rest of Loop Continues, based on "variable"]
```

Where am I going wrong here? Is case_when not suited for this? I can use nested ifelse() statements to assign the dataframe I want to "variable" based on where I'm at in the loop, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a `switch()` here:

```
for (i in analyses) {
    variable = switch(
        i,
        'red' = data.frame.a,
        'green' = data.frame.b,
        'blue' = data.frame.c
    )
    [Rest of loop]
}
```

Nested `if/else` statements work here too, but can be clumsier to add on if you have more cases that you want to cover. The advantage to using `switch() is just that you add the next case in the same way as all the others, and it keeps variable assignment to a single function while still incorporating your cases. It can also handle what do if none of your cases are met.

Answer (score 0):

Put the dataframes in a list, if you need to keep track of colors assign names to the list.

```
list_data <- list(data.frame.a, data.frame.b, data.frame.c)
names(list_data) <- c("red", "green", "blue")

for (i in seq_along(list_data)) {
  variable <- list_data[[i]]
  color <- names(list_data)[i]
  
  #[Rest of Loop Continues, based on "variable"]
  
}
```